Select records from the last x days, getting RU Limit error
I'm trying to get the records from x days in CosmosDB. Our data looks like this:
[
    {
    "id": "d53a0c8c-c88f-4e5f-af3d-052d2dd752d9",
    "ModifiedDate": "10/18/2023 10:56:14 PM",
    "_ts": 1698204127
    }
]

However, when I try the following query, I get the error Request Unit limit per Operation call exceeded. I'm still pretty new to doing native queries off of CosmosDB so can anyone advise where I'm going wrong?
SELECT c.webTrfId, c.ModifiedDate, c._ts FROM c
WHERE c.clientId = 999999998 AND c.ActionType = 'Save Protocol'
AND c._ts >= DateTimeToTimestamp(DateTimeAdd('day', -30, GetCurrentDateTime()))/1000


You haven't shown any of your database/container settings, but... every operation has a Request Unit (RU) cost - these are allocated on a per-second basis. A single operation will complete, but if going over allotted RU/sec, you are in "RU debt" for maybe a second or two until you pay that debt off. In your case, if you can't even run a single query, then you likely set a limit that can't be exceeded. But... you'd really need to edit to show all details, not just a single query and nothing else.

It says our RU Threshold is 5000. Unfortunately, I'm not a DB admin so I can't make any changes to it. When I ran the same query on Power BI, it worked. Would adding a TOP x to the query help make it run if I just wanted to see if the query works or not?

This is just a client side setting in the data explorer in the browser. It only affects your session and you don't need to be a db admin to change it as it only affects you and doesn't make any changes to the DB. But you should look at the indexing policy to see why this query is taking so much RU. Are you not indexing all the relevant properties? clientId, ActionType, _ts?

I can't really answer that question as I am not involved in the creation of these containers. Is there a way for me to check the indexing policy?

In data explorer expand the container (as you are presumably already doing to run this query) and then select "Scale and Settings" and the "Indexing Policy" tab.

You need to ensure that you set appropriate RU in the "Enable RU Threshold" section for their query in Data Explorer as shown below.
or you can disable that feature "Enable RU Threshold" so that entire collection's throughput is applied if you do not want to set a limit.

